# Set up a dynamic goal value from the script without ecommerce tracking

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

Is there any way to set a dynamic goal value in the goal page?

I've used this code (that obviously didn't work):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'GoalValue', 'BookingForm', 'Finalize', 120]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/final-page']);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Event goal and then use that event as the goal and the value of the event as a goal value. But if you choose to use Event based goals you won't have the funnel.

In that case I would create both, a Url based goal with value 0 just to track the funnel and another event based goal to set the correct value for the conversion.